# Геотаргетинг в Беларусь на Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, геолокация, wordpress-плагины

Возможен ли вывод страниц в зависимости от ip по городам и населённым пунктам Беларуси?

Comment: Попробуйте https://sypexgeo.net/ru/ Должна работать для Беларуси. Не плагин, но использовать очень просто.

Comment: Использовал для России, работает неплохо.

Comment: Это позволит мне выводить именно страницы wordpress-а по геолокации? или только в страницах смогу использовать?

Comment: Код позволяет выводить что угодно и как угодно. Если вы владеете WordPress в достаточной мере. Из вопроса непонятно, что именно вы пытаетесь сделать. Уточните вопрос, дам ответ.

Comment: Я собираюсь выводить контент в коде php сайта wordpress, а так же в страницах и списях админ панели, в завсисимости от Ip-адреса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поместите файлы SxGeo.php и SxGeoCity.dat с сайта https://sypexgeo.net/ в папку вашей темы. Добавьте такой код в functions.php:

```
global $user_ip, $user_city, $SxGeo;

require_once( trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory() ) . 'SxGeo.php' );
$SxGeo     = new SxGeo( trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory() ) . 'SxGeoCity.dat' );
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"])) {
    $user_ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
} else {
    $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
$user_city = $SxGeo->getCityFull( $user_ip );
```

Этот код подключает библиотеку Sypex Geo и определяет местоположение по ip-адресу. `HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP` нужен в том случае, если ваш сайт работает через Cloudflare.

Для определения страны, области и города используйте в нужном месте глобальную переменную `$user_city` следующим образом:

```
if ( 'Россия' === $user_city['country']['name_ru'] ) //...
if ( 'Санкт-Петербург' === $user_city['city']['name_ru'] ) //...
if ( 'Ленинградская область' === $user_city['region']['name_ru'] ) //...
```

Примеры взяты из рабочего кода.

Comment: Это определённо мне подходит. Обязательно использую ваш пример.

Comment: Дайте знать потом, работает по Белоруссии или нет. Интересно.

Comment: Да, хорошо, обязательно

Answer (score 0):

С помощью плагина [WT Geotargeting Pro](https://web-technology.biz/cms-wordpress/plugin-wt-geotargeting) можно реализовать отображение страниц соответствующих городам Беларуси.

В недавнем обновлении плагина появилась поддержка сервиса геолокации [Sypex Geo](https://sypexgeo.net/ru/), упомянутого в других ответах. Таким образом, теперь можно определять города посетителей из Беларуси по IP-адресу.

Определив город посетителя вы можете динамически изменять контент страниц с помощью шорткодов или сделать разные страницы и динамически менять ссылки в меню.